# Can MongoTemplate provide automatic translation?

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data

I have a simple persistent pojo like:

```
public class Peristent {
    private String unsafe;
}
```

I use Spring Data mongoTemplate to persist and fetch the above object. I also need to encrypt the Persistent.unsafe variable and store a complex representation of that in backend, everytime I try to save Persistent object.

Can I annotate Persistent, or provide some sort of hooks where I can make the aforementioned translations without me having to do that in the Pojo code manually. This has to happen automatically during mongoTemplate.insert.

Comment: Have you looked at @Convert construct from spring JPA

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/Convert.html cites good examples

Comment: @Shibashis I don't think the OP is using JPA with MongoDb.

Answer (score 0):

Spring Data currently only support Type based conversions. There is an [issue for supporting property based conversion](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATACMNS-1036?jql=project%20%3D%20DATACMNS%20AND%20text%20~%20conversion%20ORDER%20BY%20updated%20DESC), which you might want to track.

Therefore annotating won't work. What you could do is, create use a separate class for the property, which just wraps the `String` and register a custom converter for that type. See http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-mongo/docs/1.10.4.RELEASE/reference/html/#mongo.custom-converters for details, how to do that.